# Ambiguous type variable arising from the use of `handle`

Tags: haskell, exception

In this code:

```
import System.Posix.Files
import Control.Exception

safeStat :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe FileStatus)
safeStat path =
  handle (\_ -> return Nothing) (getFileStatus path >>= (return . Just))
```

I'm getting this error (in ghci):

```
Ambiguous type variable `e0' in the constraint:
  (Exception e0) arising from a use of `handle'
...
```

I can get rid of the error by doding something like:

```
nothing :: IOException -> Maybe a
nothing _ = Nothing

safeStat :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe FileStatus)
safeStat path =
  handle (return . nothing) (getFileStatus path >>= (return . Just))
```

What's going on??? I'd like the hander to handle *any* exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ambiguous type variable` means that compiler can't inference type. Because it can be many of datatypes with instance of [Exception](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Control-Exception.html#t%3aException) typeclass. You can use [SomeException](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Control-Exception.html#t%3aSomeException) for handling any exception. For example:

```
safeStat :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe FileStatus)
safeStat path = handle errorHandler $ fmap Just $ getFileStatus path
  where
    errorHandler :: SomeException -> IO (Maybe FileStatus)
    errorHandler _ = return Nothing
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SomeException` value in pattern matching of your lambda function:

```
import System.Posix.Files
import Control.Exception

safeStat :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe FileStatus)
safeStat path =
  handle (\(SomeException _) -> return Nothing) (getFileStatus path >>= (return . Just))
```